# Cannot autoscale Redis cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a Redis cluster with `R5.4xlarge` instances in `EU Frankfurt` region. I have 5 shards and each shard has 3 replicas each. I am not able to autoscale this cluster. From the AWS docs, I know that AWS Elasticache provides autoscaling by increasing

1. Number of shards or
2. Number of replicas

From the docs :-

```
ElastiCache for Redis supports scaling for the following dimensions:

Shards – Automatically add/remove shards in the cluster similar to manual online resharding. In this case, ElastiCache for Redis auto scaling triggers scaling on your behalf.

Replicas – Automatically add/remove replicas in the cluster similar to manual Increase/Decrease replica operations. ElastiCache for Redis auto scaling adds/removes replicas uniformly across all shards in the cluster.
```

However, I am not able to find the provision to autoscale based on metrics. Is autoscaling possible for the above configuration of cluster in `EU Frankfurt` region or am I missing out on anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoscaling is disabled for the instances of size `4xlarge` and that is the reason you cannot find `Autoscaling` tab enabled for your cluster. From the AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/AutoScaling.html, only the following AWS instances and their sizes support autoscaling

```
ElastiCache for Redis Auto Scaling is limited to the following:

Redis (cluster mode enabled) clusters running Redis engine version 6.0 onwards

Instance type families - R5, R6g, M5, M6g

Instance sizes - Large, XLarge, 2XLarge

Auto Scaling in ElastiCache for Redis is not supported for clusters running in Global datastores, Outposts or Local Zones.

AWS Auto Scaling for ElastiCache for Redis is not available in the following regions: China (Beijing), China (Ningxia), AWS GovCloud (US-West) and AWS GovCloud (US-East).
```

Comment: I modified the cluster to `2xlarge` instances and the `autoscaling` tab is now enabled. Thank you :)